# Tab through Edit boxes doesn't work C++

Tags: c++, winapi, tabbing

Well hello,

I have a problem and I didn't find any solution to this by searching; basically I want to make a simple login where you can switch through the controls ( username, password, login button ) with tabbing.

The only thing happening when pressing TAB is that it just completely selects the text from the current edit box.

Here's my code:

```
HWND g_hLogin1, g_hLogin2, g_hLogin3;
#define ID_BUTTON_LOGIN     201

    LRESULT CALLBACK LoginProc( HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
    {
        switch( uMsg )
        {
            case WM_CREATE:
            {
                g_hLogin1 = CreateWindow( "EDIT", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 50, 40, 200, 20, hWnd, 0, 0, 0 );
                g_hLogin2 = CreateWindow( "EDIT", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_PASSWORD, 50, 80, 200, 20, hWnd, 0, 0, 0 );
                g_hLogin3 = CreateWindow( "BUTTON", "Login", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 100, 120, 100, 22, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_BUTTON_LOGIN, 0, 0 );

                HFONT font = CreateFont( 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "Arial" );
                SendMessage( g_hLogin1, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)font, 0 );
                SendMessage( g_hLogin2, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)font, 0 );
                SendMessage( g_hLogin3, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)font, 0 );

                break;
            }

            case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                PostQuitMessage( 0 );
                return 0;
            }

case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            if( wParam == VK_TAB )
            {
                HWND hNext = GetWindow( hWnd, GW_HWNDNEXT );

                if( !hNext )
                    hNext = GetWindow( hWnd, GW_HWNDLAST );

                SendMessage( hNext, EM_SETSEL, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)-1 );
                SetFocus( hNext );
            }

            break;
        }

            case WM_PAINT:
            {
                PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                HDC hDC = BeginPaint( hWnd, &ps );

                HFONT font = CreateFont( 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "Arial" );
                SelectObject( hDC, font );

                RECT rc[] =
                {
                    { 50, 22, 0, 0 },
                    { 50, 62, 0, 0 }
                };

                DrawText( hDC, "Username:", -1, &rc[ 0 ], DT_NOCLIP );
                DrawText( hDC, "Password:", -1, &rc[ 1 ], DT_NOCLIP );

                EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );

                break;
            }

            case WM_COMMAND:
            {
                if( LOWORD( wParam ) == ID_BUTTON_LOGIN )
                {
                    int len1 = GetWindowTextLength( g_hLogin1 );
                    int len2 = GetWindowTextLength( g_hLogin2 );

                    char* username = new char[ len1 + 1 ];
                    char* password = new char[ len2 + 1 ];

                    GetWindowText( g_hLogin1, username, len1 + 1 );
                    GetWindowText( g_hLogin2, password, len2 + 1 );

                    if( g_pServer->Login( username, password ) )
                    {
                        ShowWindow( g_hLogin, SW_HIDE );
                        ShowWindow( g_hMainWnd, SW_SHOW );
                    }
                }

                break;
            }

            default:
                return DefWindowProc( hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam );
        }

        return DefWindowProc( hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam );
    }

bool SetupClass( HINSTANCE hInstance, char* szClassName, WNDPROC wndProc )
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = { 0 };
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof( WNDCLASSEX );
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject( WHITE_BRUSH );
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor( 0, IDC_ARROW );
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon( hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDI_ICON1 ) );
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon( hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDI_ICON1 ) );
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wc.lpszMenuName = "";
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    return RegisterClassEx( &wc );
}

int APIENTRY WinMain( HINSTANCE hThis, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmd, int iCmd )
{
    if( !SetupClass( hThis, "zcfw001", LoginProc ) )
        return 1;

    g_hLogin = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, "zcfw001", "Login", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 300, 200, 0, 0, hThis, 0 );

    if( !g_hLogin )
        return 1;

    ShowWindow( g_hLogin, SW_SHOW );

    MSG msg;
    while( 1 )
    {
        if( PeekMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
        {
            if( msg.message == WM_QUIT )
                break;

            if( !IsDialogMessage( g_hLogin, &msg ) )
            {
                TranslateMessage( &msg );
                DispatchMessage( &msg );
            }
        }
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: I imagine that is the win32 api, if so, you should tag it as such. There is no graphical UI in plain C++. Also "login" does not seem an appropriate tag for this question, which is only about switching focus, whether in the login screen or any other screen should not make any difference

Comment: If your goal is to have a functional keyboard UI, then the solution is not to break it by handling `WM_KEYDOWN`.

Comment: Is this code for a game or some other similar program? Using `PeekMessage` is as far as I know not common for typical programs, and you don't seem to be doing any calls inside your message pump when `PeekMessage` doesn't find any messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `WS_TABSTOP` style to make tab stops working.